# How do I structure my Symfony2 project with private Bundles?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony2 project, where I have a Bundle that is generic (GenericBundle) accross multiple projects, and a site-specific Bundle (SpecificBundle) that is a child-bundle of GenericBundle.

When I am developing I want the GenericBundle to be loaded locally, from a specific directory, but when deployed I want it to behave as a normal VendorBundle.

I have setup my main composer.json in my Symfony2 project with this setting which makes it load the GenericBundle from my directory when developing:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-0": { "": "../genericBundleDirectory/" }
},
```

This works fine, but how do I get the GenericBundle to load like a VendorBundle only in production-environment?

Comment: Why do you want it loaded locally when developing?

Comment: @Jacob because the purpose of this bundle is to hold the main functionallity for the SpecificBundle, and is also under development, so I need to be able to alter that during development as well.

Comment: You can tweak app/autoload.php.

Comment: The bundles in the vendor directory are version controlled. You can develop on them as you would with any other repository. You can set the version requirement in your composer to "dev-master" for your "private" bundle so when you deploy to production you get the latest changes or you can tag your commits or use releases like you would with any other repository. You achieve all your goals this way using a consistent set up for development and production, but under development you'll have all the cutting edge changes, without even committing because the changes are done in place.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would have an src/ directory to accomodate your AppBundle and/or other bundles related to your application.

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
```